# How to hide the 0 value on an axis?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Having a tick label at 0 is rather useless and takes up space. I want all of the tick labels to stay exactly where they are, except I simply want to hide the 0 tick label on the x and/or yaxis. How would I do this?

Thanks,

Nick

[image]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that we're on different Plotly versions, and that this cosmetic detail has been improved for newer versions. Making a histogram with the `px.data.tips()` dataset by running `px.histogram(px.data.tips(), x = 'total_bill')` gives me this plot:

[image]

Give it a try and see if you're getting the same result. If it does, then my only current suggestion is this:

---

The approach below will likely turn out to not be suitable for all cases. And it is admittedly a bit cumbersome. However I'm willing to explain all the details if it is something you can use. In short, the approach simply skips the zeros in `fig.update_xaxes(tickvals = ticksx)`. And that turns this sample plot:

[image]

... into this:

[image]

#### complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

# px.histogram(px.data.tips(), x = 'total_bill', y = 'tip')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[0,10,20,40], y = [40,20,10,0]))

figx = fig.data[0].x
figy = fig.data[0].y

ticksx = list(np.linspace(min(figx), max(figx), endpoint = True, num = 5))[1:]
ticksy = list(np.linspace(min(figy), max(figy), endpoint = True, num = 5))[1:]

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals = ticksx)
fig.update_yaxes(tickvals = ticksy)

fig.show()
```